# Distinct value required from 2 tables while using join

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using inner join and i want distinct values from both the tables and in my query i am selecting columns from both the table.
something like

```
select countryid,countryname,city from country 
inner join city 
on country.id=city.id
```

I am able to use distinct like

```
select distinct t.countryid from (select countryid,countryname,city from country 
inner join city 
on country.id=city.id) as t
```

but i am not able to use city like this

i want something like select distinct country,city

how to do that

Comment: `select distinct countryname,city from country 
inner join city 
on country.id=city.id`?

Comment: @FelixPamittan what exactly you mean?

Comment: Does the query above give the correct result?

Comment: @FelixPamittan its just the scenario of my query its not the actual query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding of this, you wish to get all the distinct pairs of Country - Cities possible after the initial join. With that in mind, something like this could be done:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT CountryID, CountryName, City
FROM Country 
INNER JOIN City 
    on Country.Id = City.id
)
SELECT DISTINCT CountryName, City
FROM CTE
```

This will provide you with all the distinct pairs of countryname and city after the join.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would suggest you use two ctes. Something like this:

```
WITH cteCountry AS(
SELECT DISTINCT countryid, countryname
  FROM country),
cteCity AS (
SELECT DISTINCT countryid, cityid, cityname
  FROM city
)
SELECT co.countryid, co.countryname, ci.[city]
FROM cteCountry AS co
INNER JOIN cteCity AS ci ON co.countryid = ci.countryid
```

Comment: hello @Rene i tried your logic in my query but still i am getting duplicates

Comment: So what exactly is your table structure and what exactly do you get as duplicate? Is it possible, that the duplicates are cities with identical name in different countries?